# How does the prototype chain really work?

Tags: javascript

If I have the following constructor function;

```
function Person(age) 

{
this.age = age;
this.talk = function() {
return “talking”;
};
}
```

And I create an object.

```
me = new Person();
```

**now this is where it gets confusing.** The prototype object inside “Object” (the base Object, I will refer it with a capital O) should be empty, as in, null. But it isn’t.

The “me” object inherits from the “person” constructor function and the “person” constructor function inherit   from the “Object” constructor function, but the prototype inside the “Object” constructor function should be pointing to Null.

Instead if I click on it. It shows that that the prototype inside Object function again inherits from Person (doesn’t make sense) and then the Prototype Object inside that inherits from “Object” again and the one inside that again inherits from “Object” and the prototype object inside it, is the one that has null.

So how is this really working? What am I missing? Why is it pointing back and forth?
[image]

Comment: __proto__ is like an alias of [[Prototype]]. It's not official but browsers implements it. The content of __proto__ is the same as [[Prototype]]

Comment: @Victor that is the very oversimplication which confused the OP. `__proto__` is not an alias, it is a property defined on `Object.prototype` only, whereas `[[Prototype]]` is an internal slot of every object.

Comment: You are right, Domino. I try to help but I'm not an english speaker. Sometimes my words are against me.

Answer (score 2):

The browser console lets you view an object's prototype under `[[Prototype]]` because that's the syntax used in the ECMAScript specification to refer to internal data of objects not accessible as properties.

Historically, browsers started exposing this internal value under the nonstandard property `__proto__`. Now that `Object.getPrototypeOf` and `Object.setPrototypeOf` have been added to the language, `__proto__` is considered obsolete and should not be used.

The prototype chain indeed follows your expectations:

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(me) === Person.prototype; // true
Object.getPrototypeOf(Person.prototype) === Object.prototype; // true
Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.prototype) === null; // true
```

What's got you confused is that `__proto__` is an accessor property defined on `Object.prototype`. Accessor properties implicitly call getter/setter functions, and these functions can compute their result based on the object they are applied to.

If `__proto__` didn't exist in browsers, we could implement it with the following code:

```
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, "__proto__", {
    configurable: true,
    enumerable: false,
    get() { return Object.getPrototypeOf(this); },
    set(value) { Object.setPrototypeOf(this, value); },
});
```

When you type `me.__proto__`, the JS engine goes up the prototype chain until it finds the `__proto__` getter function defined on `Object.prototype`, but it then implicitly calls that function with `me` as its `this` argument, therefore returning the protoptye of `me`.

When you go in the browser's console and unfold `me`, then `[[Prototype]]`, then `[[Prototype]]` where you can find `__proto__`, you are manually doing what the JS engine does to lookup properties in the prototype chain. What's a bit counterintuitive is that the value shown inside `__proto__` will be `me`'s prototype, despite being displayed deeper in the tree. That's because the `this` argument doesn't change as you unfold `[[Prototype]]` entries in the debugger.

Comment: Your example of using Object.getPrototypeOf has helped a lot. However, Could you please further elaborate on "And when you go in the browser's console and unfold me, then [[Prototype]], then [[Prototype]], then __proto__, it counterintuitively evaluates me.__proto__, ignoring the two levels of [[Prototype]] you've unfolded in between." Also what do you mean by counterintuitively? So is this in a way a bug or the browsers inaccuracy or it's incapability of correctly displaying the chain? Thank you and looking forward to your response.

Comment: It's not a bug, it's just a slightly counterintuitive behavior. I've updated my answer, hopefully it's a bit clearer now.